# Unable to call @Composable function from remember block

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, composition

I want to calculate height of Box in a function and I want compose to remember its result and not call that function again. That function has some composable content and therefore it is a `@Composable` function.

The problem is that, Compose won't let me call this function from `remember` block.

This is the code that I have:

```
val coverImageHeightInDp = remember {
    viewModel.calculateTopCoverHeightInDp()
}

Box(modifier = Modifier
    .then(modifier)
    .fillMaxWidth()
    .height(coverImageHeightInDp)
)
```

And the function in `viewModel`:

```
@Composable
fun calculateTopCoverHeightInDp(): Dp {
    val originalImageDimens = Size(1440f, 828f)
    val imageRatio = originalImageDimens.width / originalImageDimens.height
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val screenWidthInDp = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp
    return screenWidthInDp / imageRatio
}
```

How can I code it in a way that the result of this function is remembered and this function is not called again, until screen rotation?

Thanks.

Comment: why are you doing UI logic in view model?

Comment: I don't want my UI to have any logic.

Comment: I don't think that is an expensive calculation. If it was me I would have put it inside composable.

Comment: If you don't do it inside composable what would happen on configuration change? Device rotation e.t.c

Comment: You generally want to keep "app/data logic" in your viewModel and "UI calculations/work" in the composables themselves, this is an odd way of handling things.

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali For me, it doesn't matter if it's an expensive calculation or not, it's just redundant. That's why I want to remember it. Also, on device rotation, the same function will be called again, and will return updated value. That's why I'm using `remember` and not `rememberSaveable`.

Comment: @ArthurKasparian Well, you know what they say, you have to be odd to be number 1. :D

Comment: I don't get the negative votes. My coding practices aside, isn't my question properly written? Doesn't it not clearly ask what I want to achieve?

Comment: @BugsHappen Best of luck to you in that regard!

Also, I think the negative votes are because you are using unconventional methods to get a simple outcome, which makes things confusing with no benefit and you stray away from best practices which have been put out by experienced people, I could be wrong though!

Comment: @ArthurKasparian Thank you! And regarding negative votes, I don't think people should be judged here by their coding style or coding practices. If a question or answer is written with precision, it shouldn't be discouraged. People don't come here to learn about best practices, they come here to get the answers to their questions, even if the answer is a simple "No, it can't be done".

Comment: You really think the built-in composables you are using have no logic in them?

Comment: @EmmanuelMtali I'm sure they do. It's a matter to preference. I prefer that my composables don't have any logic in them, except for logic (if conditions) to add or not add a specific composable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your computation functions requires some variable from @Composable scope you can just pass the variable you get in composition such as density or configuration

```
fun calculateTopCoverHeightInDp(configuration: Configuration): Dp {
    val originalImageDimens = Size(1440f, 828f)
    val imageRatio = originalImageDimens.width / originalImageDimens.height
    val screenWidthInDp = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp
    return screenWidthInDp / imageRatio
}
```

And use it as

```
val configuration: Configuration = LocalConfiguration.current

val calculatedHeight = remember(configuration){
    calculateTopCoverHeightInDp(configuration)
}
```

Also you can check out this answer for difference between Composable and non-Composable functions.

[What are differents between Composable function and normal function in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73220189/what-are-differents-between-composable-function-and-normal-function-in-android/73261429#73261429)

Comment: Now that’s what I wanted to see. A proper answer with a hint of best practice.
Thank you!