# How can I create a lambda for a composable?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Consider the following code:

```kotlin
    @Composable
    private fun SomeComposable() {
        val lambda = {
            Button(onClick = {}) {
                Text("hello")
            }
        }
    }
```

That gives me an error on the `Button` with

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
> @Composable function

So, how can I create a lambda for a composable? (I want to pass this around later on to another component).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as

```
val lambda = @Composable {
    Button(onClick = {}) {
        Text("hello")
    }
}
```

Composable functions are like suspend functions you need to call them inside @Composable annotation

[What are differents between Composable function and normal function in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73220189/what-are-differents-between-composable-function-and-normal-function-in-android)